# Grunt Build Failure : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, mean-stack

```
Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task
Generating ".tmp/concat/app/app.js" from: ".tmp/concat/app/app.js"...ERROR
>> error: couldn't process source due to parse error
>> Maximum call stack size exceeded
Warning: Task "ngAnnotate:dist" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I am developed a mean stack app using yo generator-angular-fullstack 3.5.0.

While doing the build, i am facing the above error on "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task.

Please help.

Comment: Probably an infinite loop created somewhere, can you add your grunt file?

Comment: Hi, 
I have posted my gruntfile.js on https://github.com/aalokit/Mean-Stack/issues/1..
Please see once and lemme know how u could help,

Comment: Hi @Und3rTow I have added the file.. Please see it to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cleary say that there is parse error.. check the HTML..may be some tags remain unclosed or any extra closing tags.

tip : validate your HTML